# implementing specification design pattern for checking a range of string properties

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

Can I use the specification design pattern to improve the following scenario?  I'm struggling to see how I can implement it?

Thanks,

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.Firstname) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.Lastname)
            && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.Email)
            && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.Username))
{
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, specification can hide this conditions. But I would not create specification if this is a only problem of your code, and if this condition is checked only in one place. Even if this check is repeated, than my first thought would be avoiding objects in invalid state - i.e. just avoid assigning `null` values to this properties. If it's not possible, then you can ask user whether it is valid or not instead of getting values from user and checking them outside of user ([Tell, Don't Ask Principle](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html)):

```
public bool IsValid // consider better name here
{
    get
    {
         return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Firstname) &&
                !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Lastname) &&
                !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Email) &&
                !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Username);           
    }
}
```

But if you are planning to create complex specifications, or you are planning to pass them over your system (e.g. pass specification to repository to get some specific objects), then it's a good idea.

Define specification interface (if you want more specifications, or if you want to mock them):

```
public interface ISpecification<T>
{
    bool IsSatisfiedBy(T value);
}
```

Create specific specification (of course, name could be more specific, like `OvertimeWorkerSpecification` which checks whether worker has some overtimes):

```
public class UserSpecification : ISpecification<User>
{
    public bool IsSatisfiedBy(User user)
    {
        return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Firstname) &&
               !String.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Lastname) &&
               !String.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Email) &&
               !String.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Username);
    }
}
```

Suppose user looks like:

```
public class User
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

Usage is simple:

```
var spec = new UserSpecification();

// then pass your user to check if he satisfies specification
if (spec.IsSatisfiedBy(obj))
    // do something

// or filter users with specification
var validUsers = users.Where(spec.IsSatisfiedBy);
```

Also I suggest you to read very good [Specifications](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/spec.pdf) article by Martin Fowler.

Comment: yeah, I think my usage is overkill as opposed to just a IsValid type call.  Thanks, great answer.

Comment: @JamesRadford welcome :) I also added link to principle which adheres this particular scenario